# (Web|Service) Worker importar script UMD - Como verificar o contexto

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker

Como verificar se o script esta sendo chamado a partir de um (Web|Service) Worker?

Tenho usado UMD a um longo tempo e estou migrando meus projetos para suportar SW ... embora, utilize muitos recursos disponíveis apenas nos objetos `window` e `document` muitas funcionalidades (utilidades) desejo partilhar no SW (importar) más acabo tendo de "duplicar" estes recursos separando-os em novos arquivos para de fato importar (`importScripts()`) pois é o mesmo que faço ao usar Web Workers.

Passei a olhar para isto de uma maneira mais "critica" e me perguntar:

> Como identificar em que contexto o código está sendo executado?

Com base neste "contexto" passar a exportar apenas um conjunto de utilidades... por hora o que tenho baseia-se nisto:

```
;((root, factory) => {
    // UMD (Universal Module Definition) [improved]
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define(['exports'], factory)
    } else if ( typeof exports !== 'undefined' ) {
        factory(exports)
    } else {
        factory(root)
    }
})(this, exports => {    

    let A, B, C    

    const A = 'a'
    const B = 'b'
    const C = 'c'    

    function Plugin(){}
    // prototype
    Plugin.prototype.functionA = function(param) {}
    Plugin.prototype.functionB = function(param) {}
    Plugin.prototype.functionC = function(param) {}    

    exports.CorePlugin = new Plugin()
});
```

Exportando tudo o que é "exportável" para o objeto `window`:

```
window.CorePlugin
```

Como poderia algo como isto:

```
function SWPlugin() {
    // um conjunto de ferramentas exclusivas para Service Worker
}

function WWPlugin() {
    // exportar um conjunto de ferramentas exclusivas para Web Worker
}

function Plugin() {
    // a exportação padrão para `window`
}

// verificar
if ( ISWORKER ) {
    exports.CorePlugin = new WWPlugin()
} else if ( ISSERVICE ) {
    exports.CorePlugin = new SWPlugin()
} else {
    exports.CorePlugin = new Plugin()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) pude chegar ao resultado esperado

```
let IsServiceWorkerContext = ( ('WorkerGlobalScope' in self) && ('ServiceWorkerGlobalScope' in self) ) ? true : false,
    IsWebWorkerContext     = ( ('WorkerGlobalScope' in self) && !('ServiceWorkerGlobalScope' in self) ) ? true : false,
    IsWebBrowserContext    = ( ('window' in self && 'document' in self) && !IsServiceWorkerContext && !IsWebWorkerContext) ? true : false
```

A única mudança foi prevenir no "scopo" global (do módulo) o uso de objetos como `window`, `document`, entre outros que não estão disponíveis em Web Workers e Service Worker.

```
const noop = () => {}
const dc = IsWebBrowserContext ? document : false,
    wd = IsWebBrowserContext ? window : self,
    nv = wd.navigator,
    ua = nv.userAgent,
    ls = IsWebBrowserContext ? wd.localStorage : noop(),
    ss = IsWebBrowserContext ? wd.sessionStorage : noop(),
    XHR = IsWebBrowserContext ? ( new XMLHttpRequest() ) : noop(),
    FD  = ( new FormData() ),
    // global get APIS...
    indexedDB      = wd.indexedDB || false,
    IDBTransaction = wd.IDBTransaction || false,
    IDBKeyRange    = wd.IDBKeyRange || false,
    URL            = wd.URL || false,
    Geolocation    = IsWebBrowserContext ? nv.geolocation : noop(),
    RegLogout      = IsWebBrowserContext ? nv.sendBeacon : noop(),
    Notifics       = IsWebBrowserContext ? wd.Notification : noop(),
    Fetch          = wd.fetch || false,
    Storage        = IsWebBrowserContext ? wd.Storage : noop(),
    Worker         = IsWebBrowserContext ? wd.Worker : noop(),
    ServiceWorker  = IsWebBrowserContext ? nv.serviceWorker : noop(),
    Promise        = wd.Promise || false
```

Usar a lógica (verificar o contexto) em algumas funções auto-executáveis e "prototipar" funções e objetos específicos ao "contexto".

```
if ( IsServiceWorkerContext ) {
    Plugin.prototype.example1 = noop()
    Plugin.prototype.example2 = noop()
} else if ( IsWebWorkerContext ) {
    Plugin.prototype.example1 = noop()
    Plugin.prototype.example3 = noop()
} else if ( IsWebBrowserContext ) {
    Plugin.prototype.example4 = noop()
    Plugin.prototype.example5 = noop()
    //...
}
exports.CorePlugin = new Plugin()
```